# Is there a way to see how many users joined my discord bot game?

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I am trying to make a discord bot text game. The users on the discord server are supposed to be able to interact with the bot and play a game (based on roles and text). Each player is to be given a role and then the bot will tell a story based on these roles.

I want to make a system where the players can type in !play or !join and as soon as there are enough players (minimalplayers = 4) and everybody does !ready, the game will start.

So here is my question: How can I make players "join/start" the game and how can I identify HOW MANY players there are?

(I am coding this with Node.js)

I have followed [this](https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/) tutorial and modified the code slightly - this is what I have so far:

```
const Discord = require('discord.io');
const logger = require('winston');
const auth = require('./auth.json');

const prefix = "!";


// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
const bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});

bot.on('ready', function (/*evt*/) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == prefix) {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
       
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            // !hello - first command
            case 'hello':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: "Hello! I am at your service!"
                });
            break;
            
            case "help":
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: "Do you need help with me or my commands?"
                });
            break;

            case "play":
                const maxplayers = 10;
                const minplayers = 4;
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: "Ready to play? We are still waiting for players"
                })
            // Just add any case commands if you want to..
         }
     }
});
```

Thank you in advance! ANY help is welcome!

Comment: You could create a variable at 0, increase it whenever someone joins to play, and when someone types !play and that variable is greater than or equal to 4, start the game. Then when the game is over reset to 0.

Comment: I tought of that too, yes, but how do I know how many players "joined" this discord game? I know that every user has an ID - but I need to make a "game" function. So how would I make a that?